# If statement over dask array

Tags: python, dask

Hi everybody can you tell me why a If statement over dask array is so slow and how to solve it ?

```
import dask.array as da
import time

x = da.random.binomial(1, 0.5, 200, 200)
s = time.time()
if da.any(x):
    e = time.time()
    print('duration = ', e-s)

output: duration =  0.368
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took at look at the dask source code. Essentially, when you call functions on dask arrays it performs a "reduction" of the array. Intuitively this is necessary because, behind the scenes, dask arrays are stored as separate "blocks" that can live individually in memory, on disk, etc. but you need to somehow pull pieces of them together for function calls.

So the time you are noticing is in the initial overhead of performing the reduction. Note that if you increase the size of the array to 2M, it takes about the same time as for 200. At 20M it only takes about 1s.

```
import dask.array as da
import time

# 200 case
x = da.random.binomial(1, 0.5, 200, 200)
print x.shape
s = time.time()
print "start"
if da.any(x):
    e = time.time()
    print 'duration = ', e-s

# duration =  0.362557172775


# 2M case
x = da.random.binomial(1, 0.5, 2000000, 2000000)
print x.shape
s = time.time()
print "start"
if da.any(x):
    e = time.time()
    print 'duration = ', e-s

# duration =  0.132781982422

# 20M case
x = da.random.binomial(1, 0.5, 20000000, 20000000)
print x.shape
s = time.time()
print "start"
if da.any(x):
    e = time.time()
    print 'duration = ', e-s

# duration =  1.08430886269


# 200M case
x = da.random.binomial(1, 0.5, 200000000, 200000000)
print x.shape
s = time.time()
print "start"
if da.any(x):
    e = time.time()
    print 'duration = ', e-s

# duration =  8.83682179451
```

Answer (score 2):

Dask array is lazy by default, so no work happens until you call `.compute()` on your array.

In your case you are implicitly calling `.compute()` when you place your dask array into an if statement, which converts things into booleans.

```
x = da.random.random(...)  # this is free
y = x + x.T  # this is free
z = y.any()  # this is free

if z:  # everything above happens now, 
    ...
```